# ObservableProperty attribute in derived class

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to use the ObservableProperty attribute in one of my VMs. How should I capture the Changed event in a derived class?

```
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

partial class PersonVM : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool isSelected = false;
}


class TeacherVM : PersonVM
{
    // How to do this?
    partial void OnIsSelectedChanged(bool value)
    { }    
}
```

Comment: You could override ObservableObject's `protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)` and check `e.PropertyName`.

Comment: Thanks @Clemens, I can do that in PersonVM, but I was searching for a baked-in solution for accessing this in TeacherVM

Comment: You can of course also do that in TeacherVM , where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the simplest implementation:

```cs
    partial class PersonVM : ObservableObject
    {
        [ObservableProperty]
        private bool isSelected = false;
    }


    partial class TeacherVM : PersonVM
    {
        public TeacherVM()
        {
            PropertyChanged += TeacherVM_PropertyChanged;
        }

        private void TeacherVM_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.PropertyName != nameof(IsSelected)) return;
            // do stuff
        }
    }
```

Alternatively, depending on your needs, you could create a virtual or abstract member that you could override in the derived class.

Comment: Thanks, I am searching to see if there are any built-in solutions that I was unaware of!

Comment: @sfm I don't think that there are. The code generators generate the rest of the partial class, but  that is just for the base class. The derived class does not have access to the partial members built by the generators in the parent class, so I think you have to interact with it doing something like what I've written above. There may be another option, but I'm not aware of it if there is.